Jira Tempo отчет
Я пытаюсь вывести отработанные часы команды за месяц в Jira Tempo (Logged Hours) отчет.
У меня есть права администратора и когда я загружаю отчет и фильтрую по проекту, каждому участнмку команды. группирую по проекту и пользователю у меня показываются только мои часы. Почему не показываются часы других участников команды, что может на это влиять?
Я перепробовал разные комбинации такого фильтра.
Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
